# How do I retrieve the top 10 of the rated reviews from my ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, accumulator

Good morning companions, i want to generate a top 10 of the best rated books (reviews), I have an Arraylist with all the books and another with the reviews entered related to each book (book id)

Class Book

```
public class Book {
 
    private int idbook;
    private String title;
    private String editorial;

    public Book(int idbook, String title, String editorial) {
        this.idbook = idbook;
        this.title = title;
        this.editorial = editorial;
    }

    public int getIdbook() {
        return idbook;
    }

    public void setIdbook(int idbook) {
        this.idbook = idbook;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getEditorial() {
        return editorial;
    }

    public void setEditorial(String editorial) {
        this.editorial = editorial;
    }
```

Class Reviews

```
public class Reviews {
    
    private int idreview;
    private int idbook;
    private int rating;

    public Reviews(int idreview, int idbook, int rating) {
        this.idreview = idreview;
        this.idbook = idbook;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public int getIdreview() {
        return idreview;
    }

    public void setIdreview(int idreview) {
        this.idreview = idreview;
    }

    public int getIdbook() {
        return idbook;
    }

    public void setIdbook(int idbook) {
        this.idbook = idbook;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

then I go through the book arraylist to get its ID and match it with the reviews entered that also have the book ID and its rating

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
       // Books
       ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<Book>();
       Book book1 = new Book(123,"Dante Aligueri","Planet");
       Book book2 = new Book(456,"Virginia Wolf","Planet");
       book.add(book1);
       book.add(book2);
       
       // Reseñas 
       ArrayList<Reviews> top = new ArrayList<Reviews>();
       Reviews top1 = new Reviews(1,123,9);
       Reviews top2 = new Reviews(2,123,9);
       Reviews top3 = new Reviews(3,123,9);
       Reviews top4 = new Reviews(4, 456,10);
       top.add(top1);
       top.add(top2);
       top.add(top3);
       top.add(top4);
       
      int sum = 0;
      int rating = 0;
      long idbook = 0;
      
      for (int i = 0; i < mybook.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mytop.size(); j++) {
                if (book.get(i).getIdlibro() == top.get(j).getIdlibro()) {
                idbook = book.get(i).getIdlibro();        
                rating = top.get(j).getRating();
                sum += rating; 
                }
               tops.setText("book id: " + idbook + "total rating" + sum);
        }              
            
   }
}
```

I am trying to get all each book with its rating, but it only shows me a single book and its respective score, could you please help me.

I try to get output like this:

```
book id: 123 total rating: 27 
book id: 456 total rating: 10
```

Comment: Well, you *could* have each `Rating` instance have a reference to its associated `Book`. It'll make things simpler, as you don't have to match by book id.

Comment: The reviews arraylist has an attribute (_idbook_) that is related to the `book araylist`, but apparently you are not getting it all with nested loops.

Comment: What kind of rating is stored in `mytop = getListReviews()` list?  Is there one rating per book (if yes, you should sort the `mytop` list by rating in descending order and pick up 10 books)?  Or are there multiple ratings for the same book and you are trying to calculate the total rating -- what is the purpose of `sum += rating`?

Comment: Why isn't it being called `topten` and holds these 10 items in descending order? There is no good reason, why `Data.getListReviews()` should be responsible for providing a list of the top 10 books — use SQL.

Comment: Alex the review arraylist, stores a rating from 1 to 5 for each book and many reviews can be entered for a single book and I must add that total rating to later show the best rated books, the purpose of the  `sum + = rating`, is to add the individual ratings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get all each book with its rating

Are you sure there will be a rating for each book?

```
for (int i = 0; i < mybook.size(); i++) {
    boolean ratingFound= false;
    sum= 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < mytop.size(); j++) {
        if (mybook.get(i).getIdbook() == mytop.get(j).getIdbook()) {
            idbook = mybook.get(j).getIdbook();        
            rating = mytop.get(j).getrating();
            sum += rating; 
            ratingFound= true;
        }        
    }
    if (ratingFound) { // Or:  if (sum>0) {
//    I would store the values in a Map which you can sort in the end,
//    since you are interested only in the top 10.
      tops.setText("book id: " + idbook + "total rating" + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is supposed to take all the reviews that contain that specific `id book` and add their rating, but it is only taking a single book, the output is showing this: `book id: 9789588763651 total rating: 5 `

Comment: This is what I hope my code will do. Did you try? The result, however, is not ordered yet.

Comment: I just tested and it only shows me a single book, and I have multiple reviews entered

Comment: I am going to create a new arraylist of reviews and enter each qualified book there, then with a "sort" I order it, but only one object is coming out

Comment: What did you sort and how? I think it's time to prepare an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with some sample data put in mybook and mytop.

Comment: From your answer to Martin Zeitler I assume that your data are in a DB. If this is true, that changes quite a lot.

Comment: The data does not come out of a database, in the interface that I created I have several jtextfield that obtains the data of each book and each review. They are filled and then I save them in ArrayList, the "review/book" is related to the idbook.  My level of English is a bit bad, I use a translator, I hope you can understand what I write

Comment: I do understand you. So please, write the SSCCE and we can test your problem. Should your English be that bad that you cannot read the given link, its gist is to reduce your code to the absolute minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem and post it here. The code must compile error free.

Comment: When it says the SSCCE is to edit the code that I uploaded?

Comment: Yes, in a way that it compiles and runs. So some data must be given.

Comment: Partner I have just created a separate code to be able to obtain the data and have a different view of the problem

Comment: It worked, there was only a problem with the idbook index (i), everything is fine, thank you very much and blessings

Comment: I experienced this quite often, that in preparing the SSCCE I found the solution myself. So good luck. - And thank you for the blessings. Blessings coming directly from the lord are something very special. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That column can easily be generated with a sub-query, so why mess around ?? Something alike:

```
(
    SELECT SUM(stars) FROM reviews WHERE reviews.book_id = books.book_id GROUP BY book_id;
),
```

Else you'll end up with a list that is not sortable.

Comment: Thank you very much, although I do not have a very good handle of SQL, I will continue investigating about it